# ON site Box Office

Tags: civievent

How do you sell tickets on-site/at the door? How is it a box office if I cant sell tickets online and at the door.

I have checked the demo out and can not find where this is done.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the event and you will see a register button. Click this and you can register people as attendees, which is the same as selling tickets. You could take cash at that point or if you have payment processors set up you can take their card details and take the money that way (or paypal or whatever you choose - just look in the docs for payment processors). For fancy stuff like USB card swiper support, see this page https://civicrm.org/comment/8092#comment-8092